# Static cross-compilation of GTK applications on Fedora for Windows?

Tags: gcc, gtk, mingw, fedora, static-linking

I'm trying to build gtk3 applications for windows and since Fedora delivers mingw and precompiled libraries for gtk3 for mingw, I used it.

I got the normal compilation working via

```
i686-mingw32-gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-win32-3.0`
```

Now I would like to link it statically (Fedora delivers precompiled libraries for that too) but i cannot get it to work. It tryed

```
i686-mingw32-gcc test.c -static `pkg-config --cflags --libs --static gtk+-win32-3.0`
```

but it results in

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng14
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lffi
```

Comment: Are you sure Fedora ships static libs for WinGW32 for GTK+3? I only see them for GTK+2 on the base repos. (Or is that what these `libgtk-3.dll.a` files are for?)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, static compilation is not supported for GTK+. Anyway, [gcc arguments order](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2010-February/msg00036.html) is important for building with mingw.